# Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, openstack, pkgcloud

I'm getting a weird undefined error when I'm triying to use pkgcloud and also the property `length` is undefined :

```
var pkgcloud = require('pkgcloud');
var Q = require('q');
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

var conn = pkgcloud.compute.createClient({
    provider: 'openstack', // required
    username: 'demo', // required
    password: 'azerty', // required
    authUrl: 'http://192.168.0.242:5000' ,
    region_name :'RegionOne'// required
});
console.log(conn);
```

At this stage I can visualize the different methods of the object `conn`, but the error is generated within the for loop:

```
var d = Q.defer();
conn.getImages(function(err, images) {

    for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
        console.log("id: " + images[i].id);
        console.log("name: " + images[i].name);
        console.log("created: " + images[i].created);
        console.log("updated: " + images[i].updated);
        console.log("status: " + images[i].status + "\n");
    }
    if (err) {
        console.log("erreur");
        d.reject(err);
    } else {
        console.log("juste");
        d.resolve();
    }
});
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

Comment: You should probably check `err` **before** attempting to loop over images

Comment: yes i tried that and got this error finaly :ERROR { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND controller controller:8774
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'controller',
  host: 'controller',
  port: '8774' }

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving array of objects please consider using `console.table();` - that will save your time. As everyone said do the error check first then if no error print output. I don't know if SO will render table in snippet so please check your browser's `console` for table output.

```js
const img = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "cat",
  created: '21-07-99',
  updated: '21-07-99',
  status: "new"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "dog",
  created: '26-07-00',
  updated: '26-07-00',
  status: "new"
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: "rabbit",
  created: '16-02-10',
  updated: '26-04-10',
  status: "modified"
}];

con = (err, image) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log("ERROR", err);
    return;
  }
    console.table(image);
 
};
con("404 not found",img); //error 404 will print err
con(null, img); //no error so img
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , so when i did the error check before the for loop , i got this error : "  Unable to identify endpoint url "

Comment: because in your `conn` you are using `region_name` instead of `region:` ?

Comment: when i replace the `region_name` with `region` i got this error :` ERROR { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND controller controller:8774
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'controller',
  host: 'controller',
  port: '8774' }
`

Comment: port: '8774'  came from ` express ` ? Can you isolate your pkgcloud code to check if it works [like here](https://github.com/pkgcloud/pkgcloud/blob/master/docs/providers/openstack/getting-started-compute.md)

Comment: the port '8774' is the port of the compute service ,but i tried to isalate my pkgcloud code and the same error is generated.

Comment: It could be that your code is fine but there is something with Nova service, try this [link](https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/50611/nova-list-error-httpconnectionpoolhostcontroller-port8774-max-retries-exceeded-with-url-v2c677d3d3c35644579fa8da9b4342e19dserversdetail-caused-by/) start from checking configuration file.